# What are the names of the lore heroes?

Tags: diablo-iii

In the lore of Diablo-3 you can see that the heroes have a specific background, with own lore and reason to enter this journey to kill evil, get revenge, etc.

those are.

- The female **Demon Hunter**.

> The female Demon Hunter in Diablo III fled from her village as a child
>   during a demonic invasion. She was the only survivor. After days, she
>   was found by a Demon Hunter and was taken in as a member. Since every
>   Demon Hunter has a story like this, it is possible that the background
>   for the male character will be similar.

[**Source**](http://www.diablowiki.net/Demon_Hunter)

- The female **Wizard**.

> This 19 year old female wizard was sent to the Zann Esu mage clan, but
>   later handed over to the powerful Vizjerei since she was a "rude and
>   uncooperative student," that the smaller mage clan could not control.
>   They hoped the harsh discipline at Vizjerei "would break her anarchic
>   spirit." Yet even the Vizjerei instructors were unable to rein her in.
>   She was continually being caught seeking out dangerous and forbidden
>   magics without care for herself or anyone around her.

[**Source**](http://www.diablowiki.net/Wizard)

- The male **Monk**.

> The monk serves the Elder Monks of the monastery, who seek to destroy
>   evil in all forms. He thinks of himself as the weapon of the gods
>   against all that is evil. He is a peaceful, patient and good man who
>   aids those who suffer, with no hatred against anyone, in contrast to
>   the Barbarian. He is adept in Martial Arts, being able to defeat
>   multiple foes without the aid of weapons.

[**Source**](http://www.diablowiki.net/Monk)

- The male **Barbarian**.

> This is actually the same individual from Diablo 2. He's aged twenty
>   years, and he's got a personality in this game. Look at his gear; his
>   [[armor]] has points on which he could impale himself. It's extra
>   protection for the harsh environment, but it's also dangerous to him.
>   The day to day life characters lead in this world is very hard.

[**Source**](http://www.diablowiki.net/Barbarian)

- The male **Witch Doctor**.

> The fearsome Witch Doctor of the umbaru is believed to be a legend by
>   many, but Abd al-Hazir has seen them with his own eyes, documented in
>   the thirteenth entry of his writings.
>
> The second most sacred belief of the tribes is their philosophy of
>   self-sacrifice and non-individuality, of suppressing one's
>   self-interest for the good of the tribe. Their most current war
>   created an intense social upheaval among the tribes due to an
>   incident, of which details are lacking, but might be the reason the
>   Witch Doctor has traveled west to Tristram.

[**Source**](http://www.diablowiki.net/Witch_Doctor#Class_Background)

But in no place (neither game or web) I found the real names of those amazing heroes. Did I miss some lore in-game where they talk about it? *or you must be nameless to fight against the evil?*

Comment: I'm sorry. This is a bad question (A question about the lore of a game, with a research and work on it)? So why I got down-vote?

Comment: The male barbarian is ***NOT*** the barbarian from Diablo II.  That was an early plan from Blizz that got scrapped.

Comment: @EBongo Could you provide a link where it talk about the Diablo 3 barbarian? i got this info on wiki (Take a look at the source). Not trying to make things up here. If you think something is wrong, you can correct it by editing

Comment: Similar question (not duplicate) with some good lore links: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68839/player-character-lore

Comment: Related to my answer to [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/68200/21619).  The details about the changed plans for the Barbarian are [here](http://www.diablowiki.net/Barbarian#Male_Barbarian.27s_Backstory), which cite a Blizz post.  It seems pretty clear they went this way though, unless the Barbarian had massive head trauma, he doesn't seem to recognize Cain, Tyrael, or others he had met in Diablo II.

Comment: Just an fyi that you should consider accepting an answer, mainly because the top one has 2 names wrong ;)

Comment: Sorry i'm very away from internet atm...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I've compiled, based on the *Diablo* lore and the *Heroes of the Storm* character backstories.

---

- *Female Demon Hunter:* **Valla**

  - *Diablo III:* [*Hatred and Discipline*, Demon Hunter short story](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/lore/short-story/demon-hunter/)

    > Valla went on, "It was a good dream... but for now it must remain just that—a dream."
    >
    > The sawyer's daughter pulled her hood up. "I'm back. I'm back, and I'm ready... to continue the hunt."
    >
    > She turned away.
    >
    > "Where do you think you're going?" Josen asked flatly.
    >
    > "Tristram. The others asked you to send the best. I am the best. I'm going, and you have less than a few heartbeats to try and stop me."
    >
    > Valla waited with her back to the master hunter, then lifted her scarf... An instant later she strode away, crested a rise, and was gone from sight.
  - *Heroes of the Storm:* [Valla, Demon Hunter](http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/heroes/valla/)

    > Valla witnessed the ferocity of the hellspawn firsthand as the demons ravaged her village and left her for dead. Now, with no people to call her own, her only allegiance is to her cause: to rid Sanctuary of the demonic filth corrupting its lands.

---

- *Male Witch Doctor:* **Nazeebo**

  - Not named in *Diablo III*, however the character background in *Heroes of the Storm* is consistent with that of the heretical Witch Doctor encountered by Benu in the [*Doubtwalker* short story](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/lore/short-story/witch-doctor/).

    > *You stray far from the truth. What is true is this: the Unformed Land is not as the high priests teach. The one you call heretic knew this. That is why he defied law.*
    >
    > Images swirled and flashed before Benu like smoke and lightning. He glimpsed the so-called heretic wandering through strange lands the young witch doctor did not know. A falling star blazed in the night sky, and Benu followed it to where it crashed on the earth—a small town beset by evil.
  - *Heroes of the Storm:* [Nazeebo, Heretic Witch Doctor](http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/heroes/nazeebo/)

    > With cabalistic incantations and vestments of feather and bone, the Witch Doctor Nazeebo calls upon spirits from the Unformed Land to aid him in battle. Few outlanders ever encounter a Witch Doctor in the flesh, without losing their own.

---

- *Female Barbarian:* **Sonya**

  - Not named in *Diablo III*, however the character background in *Heroes of the Storm* seems consistent with that revealed in the game.
  - *Heroes of the Storm:* [Sonya, Wandering Barbarian](http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/heroes/sonya/)

    > From the frozen Dreadlands of the north come the mighty Barbarian warriors. After surviving the destruction of her home and death of her tribe, Sonya wanders Sanctuary in search of battle and a better life for her people.

---

- *Male Barbarian:* **Kehr Odwyll** (questionable)

  - The *Diablo III* [Barbarian short story *Wayfarer*](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/lore/short-story/barbarian/) names the protagonist, but notes that he lacks the beard and long hair typical of Barbarian warriors. Either Kehr is not the same Barbarian in the game, or some time has passed and he has grown more hair.

    > The peasant took a few quick steps ahead, trying to catch Kehr's eye. "I doubted at first. You lack the wild beard and locks mentioned in the tales..."
    >
    > He cleared his throat.
    >
    > "If you do not want to speak, I understand. I wanted only to thank you."
    >
    > Tilting his head in a bow, he let the barbarian stride past.

---

- *Female Wizard:* **Li-Ming**

  - *Diablo III:* [*Firefly*, Wizard short story](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/lore/short-story/wizard/)

    > But understand this: Li-Ming did not lie. There are tomes within our library that describe the events that may now be coming to pass. It all begins with a star falling from the heavens, and such a star did fall the day I fought Li-Ming.
    >
    > I know the true nature of magic and of who and what I am. Li-Ming knows these things as well, but she has come to a different course. This is the puzzle put before us, assassin. I am not blind to the evil that stalks us, but I fear for what Li-Ming might seek to undertake. Thus I consign to death my brightest student, perhaps the world's best hope for salvation, and pray that I have chosen rightly.
  - *Heroes of the Storm:* [Li-Ming, Rebellious Wizard](http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/heroes/li-ming/)

    > It’s a generally agreed upon fact of life among the denizens of Sanctuary that wizards and magical mayhem are never far apart. Although she understands people’s concerns, Li-Ming is entirely unapologetic for the destruction in her wake. She delights in unleashing devastating spells on her foes from afar, then teleporting away to frustrate her enemies’ attempts at striking back. Small minds may fear this kind of power, but Li-Ming wields the arcane forces of the universe with confidence and unmatched skill.

---

Comment: The links for `Heroes of the Storm` doesn't show the story itself, they're "coming soon". Also, add the story into your answer (when possible) in case of the link change/broke/source change, to keep it alive. The `Diablo III` links works, but could you summarise it ?

Comment: I read. The point is. Adding a comment like "lags behind the one in-game", for me is 'there is info there, just not as much as the ones in-game' ... the reality is that the info isn't there at all. Also, adding the text will help others. **other point** the info on the battle.net website is **HUGE**, if you can summarise it to your answer it will be great.

Comment: It has become a good-to-great answer =) hope it will be complete soon (when the sites update their info)

Answer (score 5):

- Demon Hunter: Valla
- Wizard: Li-Ming
- Monk: unknown
- Witch Doctor: unknown
- Barbarian: not sure (*could be* Kehr, but there is no good indication in the back story)

The Demon Hunter & Wizard names are mentioned in their respective short stories. Also, Li-Ming is a disciple of the Sorceress in Diablo 2.

Unlike these, the ones for WD and Monk take a different approach, talking primarily of their compatriots with a brief mention of the nameless individual going to Tristram.
**Zhota**'s story mentions *another* monk he respected being sent to investigate Tristram. The witch doctor **Benu** is already dead, his story also mentions another WD who went to search for the Falling Star.

Answer (score 1):

Being nameless is part of the lore. In Diablo 1, you are Aidan. But, in Diablo 2, you are one of the nameless heroes who defeat the Prime Evils. In Diablo 3, Cain refers to these nameless heroes as just "heroes," avoiding specifying names. This is because there is no limitation that you travel with only one Wizard, that you travel with the same Barbarian, or that your team must include a Demon Hunter. In future lore, the events of Diablo 3 will describe "heroes" who defeated the Lesser Evils, nameless once again.

Comment: You were only Aidan if you played the warrior in Diablo 1.

Answer (score 0):

Nazeebo is the current name for the witch doctor,I say this is his name because he was selected for the Nexus tournament(heroes of the storm), along with Sonya, Valla, Tyrael and Diablo, all of which are cannon names. also Valla was not the sole survivor on the attack on her town, her sister Halissa escaped with her but drowned in a river when she lost her sanity

Comment: Where did you get this information? Provide links to sources.

Answer (score 0):

I do know that the female barbarian's name in the story line is Chelsa. I watched a cinematic clip in game yesterday where the enchantress, during the rescue quest, called her Chelsa. I hope this helps! :)